# Running a SQL Server PHP Script in background WAMP

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, batch-file, wamp

I've got a script that connects to SQL server to pull some data over to a MySQL database, and I'm wanting to set up scheduled tasks to run this on a regular basis. Ideally it should run in the background, but I'm not too fussed if it opens/closes something.

I've made a bat file with the script

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0\php.exe "C:\wamp\www\data\import.php"
```

However it doesn't seem to like the fact it's connecting to SQL Server and it erroring with

```
PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in c:\wamp\www\includes\connection.php on line 4
```

Which it doesn't throw when running it in a browser.  Any ideas?

Comment: The CLI PHP and Browser PHP have different `php.ini` files. Did you enable the sql extension in the CLI `php.ini`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your command line PHP (CLI) does not have the SQL Server extension activated.

Try to:

- Check your `php.ini` file (the CLI-specific one, not the Apache one)
- Run `php -m` to see what modules are activated in command line.